# sending mails using MailMessage class - Limitations OF BCC and CC counts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage, bcc

i have a list (1,000,000 emails addresses) of my customers and i want to send them an specific email (all of those emails are the same) using MailMessage calss.
is there any limitation(s) about Ensemble Emails using this class or global rules about this issue for spammers?
also is there any limitation about bcc and cc count ?
**can i send one email with one million bcc addresses?**

thanks in advance

Comment: did i do something wrong ? why downvote? just a clear Q!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are deeply wrong in your approach:

- do not bother this 1.000.000 customers with same not customized emails, surely not all of them are interested in the same service or product (btw I doubt they are really all your customers, if you have so many customers you had an IT department and people who knew the answer);
- bcc is not to be used in general except rare cases;
- if you put 1.000.000 email addresses in the bcc or cc field, it will probably explode in the SMTP server and even if not it will take ages to send and deliver and you will have more metadata than the real email content.
- just do not do it, if you want to do smart marketing or ninja/viral marketing select a subset of those customers aggregating by business or by other factors (location, needs...) and contact the smaller subset with a real offer interesting only for those.

Answer (score 1):

No idea bout downvote.

But the restrictions on No. of ids in a mail is usually restricted by the Email Server's admins at server side. If your having probs sending all at ones, just break it down to chunks.

Again, if your using an authenticated way to send an email (supplying pass and unames), then your email server wont treat you as spammer so you can send the emails as your wish.

Btw, please note that billion email ids at 1 shot is a huge pain for your server unless its a server farms like google has :)

Comment: thanks for answer / did u know any farm that can do this job for me online ? (i really really like farms)

Comment: Nope sorry, but as i said its a huge pain even if any service provider does provide you that feature, coz what if 1000 people start sending billion emails each? Perhaps rackspace? No idea mate.

Answer (score 0):

One million emails? Use constant contact or mailchimp or other 3rd party service (rackspace now offers it to).

Even if you could create and send it, you'll end up blacklisted or destined for the spam folder of a very high percentage of intended recipients.